# still have "windows" partitions after installing ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, windows

I have looked at similar questions on what I have, for example [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737862/how-to-resize-a-windows-partition-after-ubuntu-installed) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884290/unable-to-delete-partition-on-windows-for-ubuntu-installation) but can't find the answer I'm looking for.

I originally wanted to do a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04, I started following [this](http://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/) tutorial. I followed step one and partitioned the disk by "shrinking the volume" of the partition. I burned the Ubuntu OS and installed it. I ended up deciding to have only Ubuntu so selected "erase disk and install Ubuntu" when I was setting it up.
I was worried I'd messed something up with the partitions so ran

> sudo fdisk -l

to see if anything looked ... odd (you've probably figured out by now that I don't really understand much and am trying to figure it out as I go along). I got this a lot of text but the bit that concerns me is this:

```
 
Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    616447    614400  300M EFI System
/dev/sda2     616448    878591    262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     878592 166305791 165427200 78.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  248225792 250068991   1843200  900M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  166305792 231632895  65327104 31.2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  231632896 248225791  16592896  7.9G Linux swap
```

Why is there still room for Microsoft? How can I change this so I have more space?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy-paste the text and use `<pre></pre>` tags to make the formatting work.

Comment: Wait, you removed the full output! That was important! You seem to have duplicate Ubuntu installs on /dev/sda and /dev/sdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer erases the disk when told so and needs to. By creating the unallocated space, unnecessary step given the goal was to have Ubuntu as a single OS, it allowed Ubuntu to be installed there.

You can now remove `sda2`, `sda3` and `sda4` and then, from a live session, move the Ubuntu partition to the left and resize to use the remaining unallocated space.