# How to add size my Windows 7 partition to Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: hard-drive

I using Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 together
the problem is my hardisk size for Ubuntu too small, how to add that from my Windows partition? 
thanks.

Comment: Go to GPARTER and there you can assign memory as much as you want.

Comment: I don't know 'gparter' unless Sanu meant `gparted` where I'd agree. gparted is a partition editor, so can create/delete/increase/decrease/move/format & more for partitions. Note: it won't touch a 'mounted' partition, so you can always boot your Ubuntu install media & run `gparted` from there if you want to adjust its size.  If you move your /boot files, you may have to rewrite your the grub MBR (so it points to the new location on disk), but easily fixed.

Comment: Similar question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/737862/how-to-resize-a-windows-partition-after-ubuntu-installed