# Swapping partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

I'm a bit new to this so apologies if I miss anything.

I have an HP Omen 15-ce0xx Laptop, currently dual booted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.04. I currently have 200+ GB to the right of Ubuntu. I don't actually need this much file space for Ubuntu which I use for work. I do require it for Windows which I play games on. The partition order is as follows:
Windows | Ubuntu | 200GB Unallocated

[Partitions are listed here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYfm3.jpg

**I want to move the unallocated space to the left of ubuntu so that windows can use it**. From what I've read, this will mess up the booting of ubuntu. **I already have all my data backed up, additionally I have system images for both OS, along with a ubuntu boot usb with Ubuntu 20.04.**

The problem is, I'm not familiar enough with Ubuntu booting to understand how to deal with unexpected errors, especially if I want to fix it after but it isn't well discussed. I could try to use gparted from a ubuntu boot usb (from try ubuntu) to move the unallocated space to the left of Ubuntu. But after doing so, if it does mess up the boot as I've heard, what steps do I take? and what instructions need to be performed to do this?

I tried looking it up but a lot of the guides are specific commands that don't always line up with others talking about the same thing exactly, or doesn't always go into enough detail, or just says it should be fine if I do it with gparted, like this one [How to resize a Windows partition after Ubuntu installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737862/how-to-resize-a-windows-partition-after-ubuntu-installed?rq=1).

The person who dual booted this for me previously (I tried it myself but grub wasn't having it) told me that apparently HP Omen's had some known problems with Ubuntu (I have experienced freezing multiple times but that's irrelevant to this),

to summarise:

- If after moving the unallocated space to the left with gparted the dual booting process breaks, what steps do I take?
- and, if so, what are the specific instructions need to be performed to do this?
- What is the truth of what actually happens, and what should I do?

Kind regards,

Ben

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Given the 19.04 is EOL & off-topic, it's data is backed up, why not disregard it (delete the partition) and do what you want.  You can install a fresh 20.04 system which is supported.  The intended upgrade path from 19.04 was to 19.10; which is EOL thus that path is gone so there is little point to keeping the *disco* system (if your box is i386; 19.04 was the end of the road & you need to return to 18.04 for i386/32-bit).

Comment: You can use GParted in a live environment to move your Ubuntu partition and I wouldn’t expect it to disrupt booting. However if you want to keep it simple just create a new partition in that space using Windows disk manager. It will appear as a new drive, perhaps D: or E: and be available for new software installation.

Comment: Hello, I just used gparted to move the ubuntu partition to the right of the unallocated space from "try ubuntu" on the usb I made. It actually worked without breaking the Ubuntu booting which is great. 

I will likely upgrade my Ubuntu to a more recent version, 20.04, next weekend (so I have more time in-case things go wrong as stuff from my work may break with newer versions).